# WINAPI Capturing right mouse click

Tags: c++, winapi, switch-statement, mouseevent

i have a problem with capturing mouse clicks. I have to cases:

-WM_NCHITTEST that Drag and Drop window (capture click&hold)

and

-WM_RBUTTONDOWN which is a rightclick conext menu

I have no idea how to combine those two so that they both could work properly. For now, only NCHITEST works - it takes all the clicks. RBUTTONDOWN is never entered. Any help with that?

```
case WM_NCHITTEST:  
        {  //Function used from MSDN
            POINT p = { LOWORD(lParam), HIWORD(lParam) };  
            ::ScreenToClient(hWnd, &p);  

            RECT r;  
            GetClientRect(hWnd, &r);  

                return PtInRect(&r, p) ? HTCAPTION : DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);  
            }
break;

case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
    KillTimer(ball, ID_TIMER);
    p.x = LOWORD(lParam);
    p.y = HIWORD(lParam);
    hPopupMenu = CreatePopupMenu();
    ClientToScreen(hWnd, &p);

    AppendMenuW(hPopupMenu, MF_STRING, IDM_EXIT, L"EXIT");
    InsertMenu(hPopupMenu, 0, MF_BYPOSITION | MF_STRING, IDM_EXIT, TEXT("Color Picker"));
    SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
    TrackPopupMenu(hPopupMenu, TPM_RIGHTBUTTON | TPM_BOTTOMALIGN | TPM_LEFTALIGN, p.x, p.y, 0, hWnd, NULL);
    DestroyMenu(hPopupMenu);
    SetTimer(ball, ID_TIMER, 1, NULL);
    break;
```

Comment: I think we need more information: in what function is this code contained ? This function should be a loop function.

Comment: This is a standard winapi function: LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam), these cases are inside a switch statement and yes it is a loop function, I thought that the whole function was to much to upload.

Comment: Guessing: [`WC_RBUTTONDOWN` is "[posted] when the user presses the right mouse button while the cursor is in the client area of a [window]".](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646242%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Your `WM_NCHITTEST` handler tells the mouse code that your client area is not a client area.

Comment: You return HTCAPTION for the *entire* client area of the window.  So you'll never get WM_RBUTTONDOWN, only WM_NCRBUTTONDOWN.  Pretty unclear how you want to get ahead here, other than just using the latter message, drag a window with the caption bar or something that looks like a caption bar.

Comment: [WM_CONTEXTMENU message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647592.aspx) details, when the system generates this message. Creating a context menu in response to `WM_RBUTTONDOWN` is wrong for more that one reason.

Comment: Hans Passant thank you, the NCRBUTTONDOWN worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can handle `WM_NCRBUTTONDOWN`:

```
case WM_NCRBUTTONDOWN: {
    if(wParam==HTCAPTION) {
        TrackPopupMenu(hMenu,TPM_LEFTALIGN|TPM_RIGHTBUTTON,GET_X_LPARAM(lParam),GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam),0,hWnd,NULL);
    }
    break;
}
```